# Add custom product input fields NopCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

Im creating a webshop for someone ,using NopCommerce 3.00.
The cliënt wants to insert productvariants with some custom fields like: ean code, length, etc. These values dont need to be shown on the front-end page, only the back-end.

I googled a lot to find a solution for this problem and found the: Product specification value mod. The problem is that it isn`t compatible with NopCommerce 3.00.

Other ways I could think of are renaming some default unused fields by modifying source code or by adding custom fields in the source code.
Source: http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/2654/new-product-fields.aspx

Should I pick one of the methods mentioned above, or is there a easier way of achieving this?

Can someone help me out what to choose or how I could solve this problem the easiest way? I think modifying or adding code will give me a disadventage when a newer version of NopCommerce gets released and I would like to update NopCommerce.

The fields will be used for exporting to a excel sheet.

**Edit:**
I want to add custom fields in screen below(productvariants):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its better that you modify the code and keep it in a file at separate location, if new version comes in, you just put your code in that one.

If you take up a module, first is you will have to take a good enough time to understand it and modify it, is the module code in MVC or ASP.NET? and than introducing it on the product variant screen will be another tough job for you, so I suggest better go with modifying the existing code.

Comment: This approach requires at the very least modifications to your view, controller, viewmodel, data model, database structure, etc. While it is certainly a viable option it is also time consuming and will have to be repeated any time you wish to upgrade your nopcommerce installation. Be aware of the trade-offs

Answer (score 1):

Is the source code for the product specification value mod available? If so, upgrading this plugin may be the easiest approach. I haven't played with v3 so I'm not sure how much the codebase has changed but in the past I upgraded a few plugins simply by changing the SupportedVersions value in the plugin Description.txt file.

I'd strongly recommend a plugin based approach. If you modify the source code directly, you will need to do so for every future upgrade to nopcommerce. I have a custom build of nopcommerce (for which I've done this) and it is a big task to upgrade nopcommerce every time a new minor or major version is released.

Comment: I have seen a few links on the web for this plugin, but they al durect me to the nopcommerce default page, it looks like a deleted page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to export the new fields you want to create you probably need to modify the source code.

If you create the new fields you could use the "export function" that's already in the admin panel and modify it to save the information from your new fields.